# Passing a value of a variable to a symfony function

Tags: symfony, twig, render

I want to render dynamicly a form in Symfony. I passing a array with elements of element names to the render method `'formElements' => array('formelement1', 'formelement2')`.

How i want to use the element names in my template to show the form labels.

```
{% for elementName in elementNames %}
    <div class="form-lable">
        {{ form_label({{ elementName }}) }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I received the following exception:

> A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in onBillBundle:Customer:new.html.twig at line 17

Is it not posible to render the form dynamicly without `{{ form(delete_form) }}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested...

```
{% for elementName in elementNames %}
    <div class="form-lable">
        {{ form_label(attribute(form, elementName)) }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

[Docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to surround variables in a twig statement with `{{` and `}}`. So your code should be:

```
{{ form_label(elementName) }}
```

But of course `elementName` needs to be a *Form* Object and not a string. You can generate them in your *Controller* like this:

```
public function testAction()
{
    // ...
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name', 'text');

    return ['form' => $form->createView()];
}
```

Comment: yes, i know... But i want so place the form elements by my own in the twig file like this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html